# Arrange winston log file for asynchronically tests run

Tags: typescript, logging, playwright, winston

I'm writing automation tests on typescript using Playwright and I want to add to use winstonjs library for a better logging experience.

I want to have a SINGLE log file at the end of each tests run (40 tests in total).

My tests are running **asynchronically** and each test writes to the log file.

How can I order the log file content in a way that I'll see the logs ordered by tests and not by timestamp?
I want the log file to looks like:

Test 1:

logs of test 1 here...

Test 2:

logs of test 2 here..

and so on

Is it possible?